# JSONException: Value 'cityId':4,cityName:'Ahmedabad 'java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

Below is the code fells. I am trying to parse jsonarray nested within JSONArray.

Json:

```
{
    "hospital": [
        {
            "hospitalId": "1",
            "hospitalName": "Sterling Hospital",
            "description": "<p>Now available in Portugese, French, German and Spanish! Very soon the tools on the website will be available in around 10+ local languages!</p>",
            "owner": "Mr. Tapan kumar Singhel",
            "email": "",
            "fax": "",
            "website": "www.bajajallianz.com",
            "hospitalAddress": "GE Plaza, Airport Road, Yerawada,   Pune411 006.",
            "phoneNumber": "020-6602 6666",
            "facilities": "Now available in Portugese, French, German and Spanish! Very soon the tools on the website will be available in around 10+ local languages!",
            "latitude": "22.312966",
            "longitude": "69.714182",
            "createDate": null,
            "flag": "3",
            "status": "enable",
            "insurance": [
                "'id':17',name: 'ICICI Lombard General Insurance Co. Ltd.'",
                "'id':18',name: 'National Insurance Co. Ltd.'"
            ],
            "cityName": [
                "'cityId':4',cityName: 'Ahmedabad'",
                "'cityId':8',cityName: 'Pune'"
            ]
        },
        {
            "hospitalId": "3",
            "hospitalName": "Apolo Hospital",
            "description": "<div style=\"float: left; width: 455px;\">Kasarvadavali Naka latitude and longitude&nbsp;</div>",
            "owner": "gopal",
            "email": "customerservice@apollomunichinsurance.com",
            "fax": "sfsdf",
            "website": "www.apoplo.in",
            "hospitalAddress": "sdsf",
            "phoneNumber": "1234 5677 78979",
            "facilities": "Kasarvadavali Naka latitude and longitude",
            "latitude": "12.936289",
            "longitude": "80.24558090",
            "createDate": null,
            "flag": "3",
            "status": "enable",
            "insurance": [
                "'id':15',name: 'ICICI Lombard General Insurance Co. Ltd.'",
                "'id':16',name: 'IFFCO Tokio General Insurance Co. Ltd.'"
            ],
            "cityName": [
                "'cityId':6',cityName: 'Baroda'",
                "'cityId':7',cityName: 'Surat'"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Java code:

```
public void setJson(String jsonstring)
    {
        try {
            JSONObject mainobject=new JSONObject(jsonstring);
            JSONArray array=new JSONArray();
            array=mainobject.getJSONArray("hospital");
            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
            {


                JSONObject jobj=array.getJSONObject(i);


                JSONArray citynamearray=jobj.getJSONArray("cityName");
                JSONArray insurancerarray=jobj.getJSONArray("insurance");
                for(int j=0;j<insurancerarray.length();j++)
                {

                    for(int k=0;k<citynamearray.length();k++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jobjcity = citynamearray.getJSONObject(k);
                        JSONObject jobjinsurance=insurancerarray.getJSONObject(j);

                        if((jobjcity.getString("cityName").equals(choosenCity))&&(jobjinsurance.getString("name").equals(choosenInsurance)))
                        {
                            hospitalnames=new ArrayList<String>();
                            hospitalidslist=new ArrayList<Integer>();
                            hospitalphone=new ArrayList<String>();
                            hospitalemail=new ArrayList<String>();
                            hospitalwebsite=new ArrayList<String>();
                            hospitaladdress=new ArrayList<String>();
                            hospitalfax=new ArrayList<String>();
                            hospitalnames.add(jobj.getString("hospitalName"));
                            hospitalidslist.add(jobj.getInt("hospitalId"));
                            if(jobj.getString("phoneNumber").equals(""))
                            {
                                hospitalphone.add("Not Available");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                hospitalphone.add(jobj.getString("phoneNumber"));
                            }
                            if(jobj.getString("email").equals(""))
                            {
                                hospitalemail.add("Not Available");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                hospitalemail.add(jobj.getString("email"));
                            }
                            if(jobj.getString("website").equals(""))
                            {
                                hospitalwebsite.add("Not Available");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                hospitalwebsite.add(jobj.getString("website"));
                            }
                            if(jobj.getString("hospitalAddress").equals(""))
                            {
                                hospitaladdress.add("Not Available");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                hospitaladdress.add(jobj.getString("hospitalAddress"));
                            }
                            if(jobj.getString("fax").equals(""))
                            {
                                hospitalfax.add("Not Available");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                hospitalfax.add(jobj.getString("fax"));
                            }

                            flag=1;
                        }



                    }

                }
            }


            if(flag==0)
            {
                hospitalnames=new ArrayList<String>();
                hospitalidslist=new ArrayList<Integer>();
                hospitalphone=new ArrayList<String>();
                hospitalemail=new ArrayList<String>();
                hospitalwebsite=new ArrayList<String>();
                hospitaladdress=new ArrayList<String>();
                hospitalfax=new ArrayList<String>();
                hospitalnames.add("No Match Found");
                hospitalidslist.add(0);
                hospitalphone.add("No Match Found");
                hospitalemail.add("No Match Found");
                hospitalwebsite.add("No Match Found");
                hospitalfax.add("No Match Found");
                hospitaladdress.add("No Match Found");

            }
```

Please help me with above code. Let me if you need anymore info. it doesn't parse sub array insurance or cityName. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please reduce this to a short but complete example. I suspect 90% of the code and 90% of the JSON is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: data for `JSONArray` `insurance` and `cityName` having direct string instead `JSONObject`, check your JSON response. Correct your response and try again

Comment: Hi Sathish: Yes. That seems to be the error. Working on it. Let see if that solves the problem.

Comment: "insurance": [
                {
                    "id": "17",
                    "name": "ICICI Lombard General Insurance Co. Ltd."
                },
                {
                    "id": "18",
                    "name": "National Insurance Co. Ltd."
                }
            ],
            "city": [
                {
                    "cityId": "4",
                    "cityName": "Ahmedabad"
                },
                {
                    "cityId": "8",
                    "cityName": "Pune"
                }
            ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is value "'cityId':6',cityName: 'Baroda'", but in your code. You made cityName has key.
Which is wrong.

Before converting Json to Object just check in Json Viewer, You will get an idea

If your Json is in this format, It should have been worked for you.

```
{
  "cityName": [
    {
      "cityId": 6,
      "cityName": "Baroda"
    },
    {
      "cityId": 7,
      "cityName": "Surat"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you still want to use the json in the same way

```
repalce 
{"cityName":["'cityId':4',cityName: 'Ahmedabad'","'cityId':8',cityName: 'Pune'"]}
with
{"cityName":["'cityId':6,'cityName':'Baroda'","'cityId':7,'cityName':'Surat'"   ] }

replace

JSONObject jobjcity = citynamearray.getJSONObject(k);

with
JSONObject jobjcity = new JSONObject(citynamearray.getJSONString(k));
```

Comment: Hi Harsha: I checked in Jsonlint and it says valid Json. Do you have anyother suggestions?

Comment: If cityName is key and value format how we can fetch value of it via which function in Android or we have to change the structure?

Comment: The Json is valid, but it is not correct for your implemation. please check the updated one

Answer (score 0):

Refer this and try to get idea http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public void setJson(String jsonstring) {
        try {
            JSONObject mainobject = new JSONObject(jsonstring);
            JSONArray array = mainobject.getJSONArray("hospital");
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jobj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray citynamearray = jobj.getJSONArray("cityName");
                JSONArray insurancerarray = jobj.getJSONArray("insurance");
                for (int j = 0; j < insurancerarray.length(); j++) {
                    String city = citynamearray.getString(j).split(",")[1].split(":")[1].replace("'","").trim();
                    String insurance = insurancerarray.getString(j).split(",")[1].split(":")[1].replace("'","").trim();
                    String cityid = citynamearray.getString(j).split(",")[0].split(":")[1].replace("'","").trim();
                    String insuranceid = insurancerarray.getString(j).split(",")[0].split(":")[1].replace("'","").trim();

                    if ((city.equals(choosenCity)) && (insurance.equals(choosenInsurance))) {
                        hospitalnames = new ArrayList<String>();
                        hospitalidslist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                        hospitalphone = new ArrayList<String>();
                        hospitalemail = new ArrayList<String>();
                        hospitalwebsite = new ArrayList<String>();
                        hospitaladdress = new ArrayList<String>();
                        hospitalfax = new ArrayList<String>();
                        hospitalnames.add(jobj.getString("hospitalName"));
                        hospitalidslist.add(jobj.getInt("hospitalId"));
                        if (jobj.getString("phoneNumber").equals("")) {
                            hospitalphone.add("Not Available");
                        } else {
                            hospitalphone.add(jobj.getString("phoneNumber"));
                        }
                        if (jobj.getString("email").equals("")) {
                            hospitalemail.add("Not Available");
                        } else {
                            hospitalemail.add(jobj.getString("email"));
                        }
                        if (jobj.getString("website").equals("")) {
                            hospitalwebsite.add("Not Available");
                        } else {
                            hospitalwebsite.add(jobj.getString("website"));
                        }
                        if (jobj.getString("hospitalAddress").equals("")) {
                            hospitaladdress.add("Not Available");
                        } else {
                            hospitaladdress.add(jobj.getString("hospitalAddress"));
                        }
                        if (jobj.getString("fax").equals("")) {
                            hospitalfax.add("Not Available");
                        } else {
                            hospitalfax.add(jobj.getString("fax"));
                        }

                        flag = 1;
                    }
                }

            }
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (flag == 0) {
            hospitalnames = new ArrayList<String>();
            hospitalidslist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            hospitalphone = new ArrayList<String>();
            hospitalemail = new ArrayList<String>();
            hospitalwebsite = new ArrayList<String>();
            hospitaladdress = new ArrayList<String>();
            hospitalfax = new ArrayList<String>();
            hospitalnames.add("No Match Found");
            hospitalidslist.add(0);
            hospitalphone.add("No Match Found");
            hospitalemail.add("No Match Found");
            hospitalwebsite.add("No Match Found");
            hospitalfax.add("No Match Found");
            hospitaladdress.add("No Match Found");

        }
    }
```

Comment: have you try this way ?

Comment: Give me few mins Haresh. I'll do that right away.

Comment: Will it work? I have a question. cityName sub array and insurance sub array has different lenghts. Don't we need two loops

Comment: In your response both array are same size that y i used one of the array length for iterating.

Comment: Yes but it's going to be different but thanks. I get it.